# VLOOKUP - Multiple Sheets

Tags: excel, vlookup

Sheet1: Column A = Computer Name, Column B = Location (to populate from Sheet2)
Sheet2: Column A = Computer Name, Column B = Location (to send to Sheet1)

I am using VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
also tried: =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:B222,2,FALSE)
also tried: =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A2:$B222,2,FALSE)
```

...but all values are #N/A

Comment: `VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$222,2,FALSE)` works for me. Are you sure that what is in A2 exists in your Sheet2 data?

Comment: If you get `#N/A` with 1st and 3rd version it means that there are no matches. Make sure computer names are the same in both sheets (e.g. no trailing spaces in one of the columns). To try it you can take two cells that look like a match and enter in any cell: `=A7=Sheet2!A15` and see if it returns `TRUE`

Comment: I was certain I had no spaces, but lo and behold there was a leading space.  So dumb.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a leading space. Thanks to @xidgel and @user3964075